# Gnus, send PGP encrypted message to address distinct from the one registered with the key?

Tags: gnus, pgp

My friend has changed email account, but I only have his old key (which only lists his other email, now defunct). How can I tell Gnus to use the key I have, but to send it to a different email?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got an answer at #gnus IRC channel. I suspected there has to be a description of this tag, but didn't know what it's called, so here:

[MML Definition](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs-mime/MML-Definition.html), the part I needed was `recipients=some@email`

Comment: I have just run into this issue due to some people having keys tied only to keybase.io. Is there an automated way to set the recipients attribute? Alternatively I was going to write some code to set up gpg aliases for these users based upon data in BBDB.

Comment: @verdammelt not that I know of, but I didn't search too much.

Comment: @wvxvw: As the answer is correct (and helped me :-)), I think you should accept it.